# Media Devices enumerateDevices not returning all the devices?

Tags: javascript

So I need to implement a Selector that let's me switch between my mics and my speakers.

I'm trying to use [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices) API for this, but when doing this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices);

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
   console.log({deviceInfos});
}
```

I'm only getting this:

[image]

At the same time, if I go to a google meet for example, here's the options in the settings:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to get the same list as Google Meet or any other service instead of the one that mediaDevices returns?

Answer (score 1):

Well after digging a little bit more, I found the answer, you gotta ask for browser permission first using getUserMedia, like so:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   audio: true,
});
```